# What is the proper way to initialize predefined member variables in multiple objects?

Tags: c++, class, oop

I do not come from an OOP background, and though I fully understand classes, this is a stylistic question that I have never found a satisfactory answer to. Say you are making a video game, and define a class called Gun. It has member variables called damage, fire rate, and accuracy. There are several pre defined guns, well say pistol, revolver, and machine pistol. Each Guns member variables are known at run time and never change. What is the proper way to initialize each gun?

You can just initialize them at run time

```
Gun pistol(10, 10, 10);
Gun revolver(20, 5, 15);
Gun machinePistol(5, 20, 5);
```

But ive been told that this is bad practice. You can define each of them as a new class inherited from Gun, then initialize all of their member variables in their constructors, but this is quite verbose, and it is difficult to keep track of all of the new classes.

You could also have all of the member variables be initialized in one constructor, like so

```
switch(whichGun)
{
case pistol:
    damage = 10;
    //etc, etc
}
```

But this requires some way to identify each gun, such as an enum which comes off as cumbersome.

What is the standard practice for this? I mainly use c++ but I would assume that this applies to most OOPL.

Comment: "ive been told that this is bad practice." - why?

Comment: *But ive been told that this is bad practice.* That's silly.  Code like this is fine.  Making a separate class for `pistol` and `revolver` would be silly since there are/can be many different pistols/revolvers that have their own stats.

Comment: There are numerous ways to do this, and which one works better depends on your circumstances.  You've left out having a data file that holds all the attributes that you read in and parse.

Comment: "The standard practice for this" is a Factory Pattern.  Apologies but I am very busy right now. I am sure this article of mine, will help: https://dbj.org/c-the-modern-factory/

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
Gun pistol(10, 10, 10);
Gun revolver(20, 5, 15);
Gun machinePistol(5, 20, 5);
```

It sounds from your post that those are the only valid arguments for constructing `Gun`. It that is true, then I would advise:

1. Add `public` `static` member functions to `Gun` to create such `Gun`s.
2. Make the constructor of the class `private` so that `Gun`s cannot be constructed any other way.

---

```
class Gun
{
    public:

       static Gun constructPistol();
       static Gun constructRevolver();
       static Gun constructMachinePistol();

    private:

       Gun(int, int, int);
};

Gun Gun::constructPistol() { return Gun(10, 10, 10); }
Gun Gun::constructRevolver() { return Gun(20, 5, 15); }
Gun Gun::constructMachinePistol() { return Gun(5, 20, 5); }
```